# Getting the daywise report from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I want to generate daywise report from two table

Table 1: opd

```
CREATE TABLE `opd` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `opd_no` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `patientid` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
);
```

Table structure

| id | Date | Time | opd_no | Patient_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | 18:30:10 | OPD/2122/1 | PT01 | Siba |
| 2 | 2022-03-03 | 18:30:10 | OPD/2122/2 | PT02 | Deba |
| 3 | 2022-03-04 | 18:30:10 | OPD/2122/3 | PT03 | Haris |
| 4 | 2022-03-04 | 18:31:10 | OPD/2122/4 | PT04 | ravish |

Table 2: ipd_pn

```
CREATE TABLE `ipd_pn` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ipd_no` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `patientid` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  `opd_reg_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `opd` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Table structure

| id | IPD_no | Patient_id | opd_Reg_date | time | opd_no | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IPD/2122/1 | PT01 | 2022-03-02 | 15:40:10 | OPD/2122/1 | 2022-03-02 |
| 2 | IPD/2122/2 | PT03 | 2022-03-04 | 16:35:10 | OPD/2122/3 | 2022-03-03 |
| 3 | IPD/2122/3 | PT02 | 2022-03-03 | 15:45:10 | OPD/2122/2 | 2022-03-03 |

T tried to generate daywise how much opdno's generated by the below query

```
SELECT DATE(Date) AS date, COUNT(opdno) AS total_opd
FROM opd 
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-02-1' AND '2022-03-28')
GROUP BY Date
```

Got output like below

| date | total_opd |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-02 | 1 |
| 2022-03-03 | 1 |
| 2022-03-04 | 2 |

But I can't generate how much ipd no's generated in this date period.

Please help.

I want a report like below

| date | total_opd | total_ipd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-03 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-04 | 2 | 1 |

I tried with join query i.e

```
SELECT DATE(Date) AS date, COUNT(opdno) AS total_opd
FROM opd 0 
INNER JOIN ipd_pn i ON o.Date = i.date
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-02-1' AND '2022-02-28')
GROUP BY Date
```

But that gives date ambiguity error.

So please try to help me how can I generate reports from both the tables.

Comment: Please add alias with date field because both tables have date field. This will remove ambiguity error

Comment: also tried with alis name sir but same abmiguity erreor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` to combine two tables in a subquery then use a flag column to represent which row from `opd` or `ipd_pn`

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(flag = 1) total_opd,
       SUM(flag = 2) total_ipd
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(Date) AS date, 1 flag
    FROM opd 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Reg_date,2
    FROM ipd_pn
) t1
WHERE date between '2022-02-1' and '2022-03-28'
GROUP BY Date
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ee49ecd5537920c7ac0707b7c74049a)

Comment: hello sir.you did't taken the ipd date,insted you have taken ipd reg_date which is actually the opd reg date..i am correcting the question a bit.can you please review your answer

Comment: done it sir.your answer is really helpful.again thanks a lot